# How to fix No suitable constructor found

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core, mapping

I have to use Enum Safe Pattern to persist in the database, just the code of an enum. When I try to run the migration, I get the error:

No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Regiao'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'codigo', 'nome' in 'Regiao(int codigo, string nome)'

I already reviewed the code, changed the constructor from protected to public, but it had no effect.

This is base class.

```
    public abstract class EnumBase<TEnum, TKey> :
        IEquatable<EnumBase<TEnum, TKey>>,
        IComparable<EnumBase<TEnum, TKey>>
        where TEnum : EnumBase<TEnum, TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>, IComparable<TKey>
    {
        private readonly TKey _codigo;

        private readonly string _nome;

        private static readonly List<TEnum> _listaDeEnums = new List<TEnum>();

        private static bool _invoked;

        public TKey Codigo => _codigo;

        public string Nome => _nome;

        public static IReadOnlyCollection<TEnum> ListaDeEnums
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_invoked)
                {
                    _invoked = true;
                    typeof(TEnum).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TEnum))?.GetValue(null, null);
                }

                return _listaDeEnums;
            }
        }

        protected EnumBase(TKey codigo, string nome)
        {
            _nome = nome;
            _codigo = codigo;

            TEnum item = this as TEnum;
            _listaDeEnums.Add(item);
        }

        public static TEnum ObterPorNome(string nome)
        {
            return ListaDeEnums.SingleOrDefault(item => string.Equals(item.Nome, nome, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

        public static TEnum ObterPorCodigo(TKey codigo)
        {
            // Can't use == to compare generics unless we constrain TValue to "class", which we don't want because then we couldn't use int.
            return ListaDeEnums.SingleOrDefault(item => EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(item.Codigo, codigo));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _nome;
        }

        public virtual bool Equals(EnumBase<TEnum, TKey> other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (other.GetType() != GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }

            return _codigo.Equals(other._codigo);
        }

        public int CompareTo(EnumBase<TEnum, TKey> other)
        {
            return _codigo.CompareTo(other._codigo);
        }
    }
```

This is the class that inherits from EnumBase

```
    public class Regiao : EnumBase<Regiao, int>
    {
        public static Regiao Indefinida { get; } = new Regiao(0, "Indefinida");
        public static Regiao CentroOeste { get; } = new Regiao(1, "Centro-Oeste");
        public static Regiao Nordeste { get; } = new Regiao(2, "Nordeste");
        public static Regiao Norte { get; } = new Regiao(3, "Norte");
        public static Regiao Sudeste { get; } = new Regiao(4, "Sudeste");
        public static Regiao Sul { get; } = new Regiao(5, "Sul");

        public Regiao(int codigo, string nome) : base(codigo, nome) { }
    }
```

This is the class where I use the Enum Regiao

```
    public class Estado
    {
        public int ChaveEstadoDne { get; private set; }

        public string SiglaPais2Pos { get; private set; }

        public string Uf { get; private set; }

        public string CodigoIbgeEstado { get; private set; }

        public string NomeOficialEstado { get; private set; }

        public string NomeAbreviadoEstado { get; private set; }

        public Regiao Regiao { get; private set; }

        public Guid PaisId { get; private set; }

        protected Estado()
        {
        }

        private Estado(Guid id, EntityStatus status, DateTime? dataCadastro, TipoProcesso rotina, int chaveEstadoDne, string siglaPais2Pos, string uf, string codigoIbge, string nomeOficial, string nomeAbreviado, Guid paisId) : base(id, chaveEstadoDne.ToString(), status, dataCadastro, rotina)
        {

        }
    }
```

and finally the code snippet where I do the mapping

```
            builder.Property(estado => estado.Regiao)
                .HasColumnName("Regiao")
                .HasConversion(
                    estado => estado.Codigo,
                    estado => Regiao.ObterPorCodigo(estado));
```

I expected the Codigo field to be mapped to the database, and on reading the Code field to be mapped back to the Regiao type. But I get the message:

System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Regiao'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'codigo', 'nome' in 'Regiao(int codigo, string nome)'.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConstructorBindingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_DatabaseCreator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
   at Bigai.CepApi.Data.Initializers.CepApiInitializer.Initialize(CepApiContext context) in D:\Projects\Dev\Bigai\CepApi\src\Bigai.CepApi.Data\Initializers\CepApiInitializer.cs:line 17
   at Bigai.CepApi.Services.Api.Configurations.ApiConfiguration.UseApiConfiguration(IApplicationBuilder app, CepApiContext context, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider) in D:\Projects\Dev\Bigai\CepApi\src\Bigai.CepApi.Services.Api\Configurations\ApiConfiguration.cs:line 48
   at Bigai.CepApi.Services.Api.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, CepApiContext context, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider) in D:\Projects\Dev\Bigai\CepApi\src\Bigai.CepApi.Services.Api\Startup.cs:line 74

How to fix this, please?

Comment: I am uncertain if this is the right answer, but: A lot of automatic deserialsiation uses the Parameterless constructor, and then manually assigns the values to fields/properties. It is also worth noting that every class has a implicit cosntructor without parameters, **unless** you code out any constructor. The implicit parameterless one vanishes and you have to code one out explicitly.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your model here.  I think you're trying to put too much logic into the model, and you'd be better off simplifying the EF stuff and dealing with all the more complicated relationships separately.  I think EF is struggling with understanding how to deal with the Generics in the base class vs the derived one, so it's struggling to reconcile the types in the available constructor with the public properties defined in the abstract base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Christopher and @GPW.

I solved the problem. In fact, the solution was right in front of me, all I had to do was create a protected builder needed for our friend Entity Framework.

In my base class I put

```
protected EnumBase()
```

And in the derived class:

```
protected Regiao() : base() { }
```

These two changes solved the problem.

Comment: but why this is the solution?